# Log browser errors and network traffic during Angular e2e (protractor) tests

Tags: angular, testing, protractor

I have two sizable Angular 7 CLI applications with good e2e coverage. Around the same time, both applications started to intermittently timing out at the start of the tests, most reliably on the AppVeyor build server. Incidentally, I can also get it to repro locally.

The basic logs just say that the tests timed out at a certain step, which isn't really useful. I suppose some kind of API call or Angular feature isn't reliable at the moment, but I don't know which one.

**How can I increase verbosity for `ng e2e` to the max?** The more output the better at this point, but at the least I'm looking for:

- The browser's network traffic (e.g. is some API giving 500s? or unreachable?)
- The browser errors (i.e. stuff you'd see in the console)

Ideally I'd increase verbosity and enable extra logging with just a flag on the command line, or a setting in e.g. the `protractor.conf` file - but at this point I'm also willing to install additional packages if needed.

I've checked [the Angular CLI e2e docs](https://angular.io/cli/e2e) but it doesn't mention "verbosity" or "log". I've glanced over [the protractor example (?) config](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts) linked on the protractor website as a reference, but couldn't find anything either.

Answer (score 1):

The below example is with **Chrome** Browser. It will fetch the errors and the Resource failures from the browser console.

**Protractor config:**

```
config.multiCapabilities = [{
    browserName: 'chrome',
    shardTestFiles: true,
    maxInstances: process.env.RUN_ON === 'local' ? 1 : 18,
    'chromeOptions': {
        'args': ['disable-infobars',
                 '--start-maximized',
                 'window-size=1920,1080'
                ]
    },
    loggingPrefs: {
        "browser": "SEVERE"
    },
    verboseMultiSessions: true
}];
```

**Fetch the Browser logs:**

```
browser.manage().logs().get('browser').then((browserLogs) => {
    if (browserLogs.length > 0) {
        console.log(browserLogs);
        let whitelistResources = new Set(['/static/', '/subscribable-resource-types/', '/Thumbnail/', '/picture/']);
        JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(browserLogs)).forEach((browserLog) => {
            let lstBrowser = browserLog.message.split('/');
            let intersection = new Set([...lstBrowser].filter(x => whitelistResources.has('/' + x + '/')));
            if (intersection.size === 0) {
                // Validate Network Failure: If URL part does not exists in the whitelistresource
                expect(browserLog.message).toEqual('');
            }
        });
    }
});
```